# How to DELETE one emoji in NSString

Tags: ios

How to Traversal emojis in NSString 
There is a NSString method used to traversal substring of NSString

```
    NSString *text = @"2012我们 ";
    [text enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [text length]) options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences  usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    printf("%s- ",[substring UTF8String]);
}];
```

Guess what is the output?

The output is :

```
    2- 0- 1- 2- - 我- 们-  - - - - - - - - - - - -  - -
```

Rather than:

```
   2- 0- 1- 2- - 我- 们-  - - - - - - - - - -
```

Like the American Flag   , it's composed by  and 
The length of a flag seems to be 4, and they are composed by two length-2-composed-character. 
while the NSString is enumerated , it gives me  and  rather than

When the string is in UITextView, the BACKSPACE in Keyboard is tapped, it can handle to delete   the emoji  rather than .

In my app, I made a custom emoji keyboard and there is a DELETE button. I want to the DELETE button works just like the system BACKSPACE button in keyboard.

Does anyone know how to handle it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a unicode expert, but I believe the problem here is that the flags are actually two characters. They're regional indicator symbols. The american flag, for example, is two distinct characters: `REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER U` and `REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER S`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Indicator_Symbol

You might have luck asking the text input system to do the tokenization for you, as it seems to understand (when deleting, for example) that they should be treated as one unit. Try using the `UITextInputTokenizer` method `positionFromPosition:toBoundary:inDirection:` to move from the end of the string to the previous character (ie pass `UITextGranularityCharacter`). You can get a tokenizer from a UITextView or UITextArea's `tokenizer` method.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 15):

To delete the last character in a UITextView, just call `-deleteBackward`

```
- (void)deleteButtonPressed:(id)sender
  {
     [self.textView deleteBackward];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a solution based on Jesse Rusak's suggestion, however even the UITextInputTokenizer seems to be unable to properly parse the text, unless of course the error is on my part :)

```
+(void)parse:(UITextField *)textfield {
    id<UITextInputTokenizer> tokenizer = [textfield tokenizer];
    UITextPosition *pos = textfield.beginningOfDocument;

    while (true) {
        UITextRange *range = [tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:pos withGranularity:UITextGranularityCharacter inDirection:UITextStorageDirectionForward];
        NSString *oneCharacter = [textfield textInRange:range];

        NSLog( @"%@", oneCharacter );

        pos = [textfield positionFromPosition:pos offset:-1];

        if (pos == nil) break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone encounters this in the modern era, know that the problem has been fixed in iOS 10 or earlier. The following Swift playground code now properly prints the flags (regional indicator symbol pairs):

```
import Foundation

var str = "2017我们"

str.enumerateSubstrings(in: str.startIndex..<str.endIndex, options: .byComposedCharacterSequences) { (substr, range, enclRange, stop) in
    print(substr!)
}
```